Non-existent URLs/slugs redirect to default Posts page
I've taken over a friend's website from a shady developer. After relaunch I find that the browser lands on the default Posts page ("/blog" in this case) for any slug that isn't an active page.
I can literally input a string of any length after domain.com/ and it will display the /blog page.
I have checked DNS, all plugins, drop-ins, etc. -- there are no redirects that I can find. I cannot for the life of me get a 404.

Could it be on the host side? Some hosts have CPanel or other platforms where you can set up redirects that wouldn't show up in the WP codebase.
